# How can I compose handler off Hapijs?

Tags: hapi.js

I need to do some additional authentication in a few of my handlers. Is there a way of doing that way in a composable way?

```
export async function handler(request) {
  const user = request.auth.credentials;
  const customer = FindCustomer(user);
  if (!customer) {
    throw Boom.forbidden('user is not a customer');
  }
  if (!customer.verified) {
    throw Boom.forbidden('customer not validated');
  }

  // actual handler logic
}
```

Is there a way to wrap this so that some routes already provide the customer in the request object ?

Comment: What auth plugin are you using?

Comment: While both the options below are valid, I just went with checking it in the handler code. That seems obvious and direct, serverExtensions though cool are not very obvious to others reading the code

Comment: I'd set up an authentication strategy and require those via config.auth object in the routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [extension points](http://hapijs.com/api#serverextevent-method-options) in the request life cycle. In your case, the 'onPostAuth' extension point would be ideal.

```
server.ext('onPostAuth', function (request, reply){

  const user = request.auth.credentials;
  const customer = FindCustomer(user);
  if (!customer) {
    return reply (Boom.forbidden('user is not a customer'));
  }
  if (!customer.verified) {
    return reply(Boom.forbidden('customer not validated'));
  }
  reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: This is awesome. But how do I make this applicable to only a few routes.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing ZeMoon's answer, you can implement the `onPostAuth` like this:

```js
server.ext('onPostAuth', function (request, reply) {

    if(request.route.settings.plugins.verifyCustomer) {

        const user = request.auth.credentials;
        const customer = FindCustomer(user);
        if (!customer) {
            return reply (Boom.forbidden('user is not a customer'));
        }
        if (!customer.verified) {
            return reply(Boom.forbidden('customer not validated'));
        }

    }

    reply.continue();
});
```

And then add a configuration `plugins.verifyCustomer` to the route:

```js
server.route({
    method: 'get',
    path: '/test1',
    handler: function(request, reply) {

        // Handler logic here
    },
    config: {
        plugins: {
            verifyCustomer: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think a more robust way would be to assign scope to the credentials when the customer is authenticated, and to require the scope in the routes you want it.